# Downloaded file in Firefox does not show space char

Tags: asp.net, firefox, download, content-disposition

I have a web site and in there I want users to download some files. 
I gave names to the files by using string in asp.net.

Lets say I gave "description file" as name to the file 1 and "sample" to the file 2.

Even though in IE and Chrome the names are shown the way they should be shown, in Firefox the first file name is shown as "description" instead of "description file".

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: there is no code i m just asking is there any diffence between mozilla and ie in therms of showing the downloaded file name. if yes what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this to work in Firefox you must surround your attachment filename with quotes.

This will yield "description file" in Chrome and IE, but only "description" in Firefox:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=description file");
```

This will yield "description file" in all three of the before-mentioned browsers:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"description file\"");
```